NullReferenceException when developing OpenXR XR_EXT_Hand_Tracking
I encountered an error when trying to invoke the delegate.
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
private xrGetSystemPropertiesDelegate xrGetSystemProperties; 
XrResult result = xrGetSystemProperties(instance, systemId, ref systemProperties);

private xrLocateHandJointsEXTDelegate locateHandJoints;
XrResult result = locateHandJoints(tracker, locateInfo, ref jointLocationsStruct);

Is there anything wrong?
I tried reading the official OpenXR documentation, but it wasn't very helpful.
